# Activity force close when I scroll listview

Tags: android

Hi I have a listview with custom adapter ... one image and two text view .... when I scroll upside activity crash ...... listview is attatched with fragment , and fragment is attatched with activity.....

logcat is

```
    FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.cuelearn.cuemathteacher.adapters.StudentsEnrollDetailCustomAdapter.getView(StudentsEnrollDetailCustomAdapter.java:64)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2255)
    at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1769)
    at android.widget.ListView.fillUp(ListView.java:706)
    at android.widget.ListView.fillGap(ListView.java:645)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:5040)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.scrollIfNeeded(AbsListView.java:3197)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:3471)
    at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7127)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2170)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1905)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2176)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1919)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2176)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1919)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2176)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1919)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2176)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1919)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2176)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1919)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2176)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1919)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1925)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1379)
    at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2396)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1873)
    at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7307)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3174)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3119)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:4155)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4134)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4226)
    at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:171)
    at android.view.InputEventReceiver.nativeConsumeBatchedInputEvents(Native Method)
    at android.view.InputEventReceiver.consumeBatchedInputEvents(InputEventReceiver.java:163)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doConsumeBatchedInput(ViewRootImpl.java:4205)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ConsumeBatchedInputRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4245)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:523)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

and this is the custom adapter file

```
public class StudentsEnrollDetailCustomAdapter  extends ArrayAdapter<StudentInfo> {

    Context context;
    StudentInfo[] arr_StudentInfo;
    static class ViewHolder{

        TextView tv_student_name,tv_student_class;
        ImageView iv_student_photo;
    }

    public StudentsEnrollDetailCustomAdapter(Context context,StudentInfo[] arr_StudentInfo) {
        super(context, R.layout.adapter_students_enroll_detail, arr_StudentInfo);

        this.context = context;
        this.arr_StudentInfo = arr_StudentInfo;

    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View rowView = convertView;
        if(rowView == null){

            rowView = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.adapter_students_enroll_detail, null);
            ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

            viewHolder.tv_student_name = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.firstLine);
            viewHolder.tv_student_class = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.secondLine);
            viewHolder.iv_student_photo = (ImageView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.icon);


            rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }


    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();



    StudentInfo s = arr_StudentInfo[position];


    if(s.getStudentStatus() == 0){


        holder.tv_student_name.setText(""+s.getStudentName());
        holder.tv_student_class.setText("Class : "+s.getStudentClass());
        if(s.getStudentImage() == null){
            holder.iv_student_photo.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_contact_picture);
        }else{
            holder.iv_student_photo.setImageBitmap(s.getStudentImage());    
        }

        CUtils.setCustomFontNormal(context, holder.tv_student_name, CConstants.FONT_F3);
        CUtils.setCustomFontNormal(context, holder.tv_student_class, CConstants.FONT_F4);


    }else{

        rowView = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.row_null, null);
    }
    return rowView;
    }


}
```

error shows in this line of custom adapter but there is no problem ..

```
holder.tv_student_name.setText(""+s.getStudentName());
```

Comment: Why you inflated `rowView` two times?

Comment: because when this (s.getStudentStatus()) method does not return 0 ..than i have to hide that item from list view ... and second inflated layout does not have content ... that contain only linearlayout without any child

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, s is null.
Which means that arr_StudentInfo[position] is null.
Which, in turn, probably means that you haven't initialized the array element at that position.
HTH.

Answer (score 0):

Once check the StudentInfor array is correct filled or not.As per exception one issue with the position wise getting the StudentInfor values.

Second : `getView` method implementation is wrong.

> because when this (s.getStudentStatus()) method does not return 0
>   ..than i have to hide that item from list view ... and second inflated
>   layout does not have content ... that contain only linearlayout
>   without any child

Than do not add those list row item in `StudentInfo[] arr_StudentInfo` which you are passing in Adapter. After removing or filtering pass that and display

in below posted code i have used `BaseAdapter`  as its the good and best option to use adapter for customized listview

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context context;
    StudentInfo[] arr_StudentInfo;
    private int size = 0;

    static class ViewHolder {

        TextView tv_student_name, tv_student_class;
        ImageView iv_student_photo;
    }

    public StudentsEnrollDetailCustomAdapter(Context context,
            StudentInfo[] arr_StudentInfo) {
        this.context = context;
        this.arr_StudentInfo = arr_StudentInfo;
        if (this.arr_StudentInfo != null)
            size = this.arr_StudentInfo.length;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return size;
    }

    @Override
    public StudentInfo getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return this.arr_StudentInfo[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
        try {
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(
                        R.layout.adapter_students_enroll_detail, null);
                viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                viewHolder.tv_student_name = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.firstLine);
                viewHolder.tv_student_class = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.secondLine);
                viewHolder.iv_student_photo = (ImageView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.icon);
                convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
            StudentInfo s = arr_StudentInfo[position];
            if (s != null) {
                if (s.getStudentStatus() == 0) {

                    holder.tv_student_name.setText("" + s.getStudentName());
                    holder.tv_student_class.setText("Class : "
                            + s.getStudentClass());
                    if (s.getStudentImage() == null) {
                        holder.iv_student_photo
                                .setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_contact_picture);
                    } else {
                        holder.iv_student_photo.setImageBitmap(s
                                .getStudentImage());
                    }

                    CUtils.setCustomFontNormal(context, holder.tv_student_name,
                            CConstants.FONT_F3);
                    CUtils.setCustomFontNormal(context,
                            holder.tv_student_class, CConstants.FONT_F4);

                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(
                        context,
                        " StudentInfo is not getting at list row position "
                                + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: @AvinashJadaun okay do you think that its working fine thn why that issue is comng ?